# Code First Entity Framework does not create database with tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I have Couple of Models (Classes).

City.cs:

```
public class City
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

Course.cs:

```
public class Course
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Faculty { get; set; }

    public int CityID { get; set; }
}
```

CourseDatabaseInitializer.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace CoursesApplication.Models
{
    public class CourseDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<CourseContext>
    {
        CourseContext _Context = new CourseContext();
        protected override void Seed(CourseContext context)
        {
            GetCities().ForEach(c => context.Cities.Add(c));
        }

        private static List<City> GetCities()
        {
            var cities = new List<City> {
                new City
                {
                    CityID = 1,
                    Name = "Paris"
                }
            };

            return cities;
        }

        public List<Course> GetCourses()
        {
            return (from c in _Context.Courses select c).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

CourseContext.cs:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CoursesApplication.Models
{
    public class CourseContext : DbContext
    {
        public CourseContext(): base("CoursesApplication")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my Global.asax.cs file :

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // Initialize the Courses database.
        Database.SetInitializer(new CourseDatabaseInitializer());
    }
```

, but when I run the application, everything is OK. After that in the solution explorer I create connection, but there is no Database with tables. This is my `web.config` with connection string:

```
<add name="CourseContext"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\courses.mdf;
Integrated Security=True"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Where can be the problem ?
I am using NET Framework 4.6.1 with Sql Express 2016.
This is ASP.NET WEB Forms project.

Comment: Where do you check to see if the DB is created on SSMS ?

Comment: SSMS and server explorer in VS with server name `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` which is part and in `connectionString` in `Web.config`

Comment: Have you run `enable-migrations` then `add-migration Init` and then `update-database`to create the database?

Comment: Same thing, no database is created.

Comment: After executing these commands, I see folder `Migrations` with couple of files in it, but Database still not create.

Comment: I see this after executin the command in the console `Applying explicit migration: 201705052347261_Init.
Running Seed method`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not targetting the correct database. Just one thing make sur all of your configurations files use the same connection string.

Comment: In VS or SSMS, I am using this for server name `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB`, which is in the connection string in Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

In `CourseContext` Try changing this

```
public CourseContext(): base("CoursesApplication")
{
}
```

to this

```
public CourseContext(): base("CourseContext")
{
}
```

or remove `: base("CoursesApplication")`